# Отправка cookies на сервер через aiohttp

Tags: python, flask, request, aiohttp

Возникла проблема с отправкой кукисов на сервер.
сразу скажу, вероятно, ошибка в том, что я пытаюсь отправить кукисы через aiohttp, а сервер же принимает это всё через обычный flask.request. Но я в этом не уверен, потому и здесь. не нашёл время, и сервер переписать под асинхронность.

сервер выдаёт 401, будто бы я не передал кукисы.

Код, которым я отправляю кукисы.

```
    c = json.loads(await get_cookies())
    # print(c) / {'name': 'session',
    # 'value': 'eyJzZWNyZXRfa2V5Ijp7IiBiIjoiWlRFMk0yTXlNelprY1RRek1qUXlNelJqTURKbSJ9fQ.ZMEP6A.y5tU5YpIcSREwHjDVnth_GSY4B4'}

    async with ClientSession(SERVER_HOST, cookies=c) as r:
        async with r.post('/register', data='data') as reg:
            if reg.ok:
                pass
```

Сервер:

```
def register():
    if request.method == "POST":
        if 'secret_key' not in session:
            # Для регистрации нужен специальный key.
            return err__none_authorization, 401

        #запись в бд и тд.
        return 'ok', 200
```

Сервер отдаёт кукисы так:

```
def authorization():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        bot_key = request.get_data()
        #для уменьшения мусора в коде все функции по шифрованию я убрал
        if bot_key == get_secret_key():
            session['secret_key'] = bot_key
            return authorization_complete, 200
    
        if session.get('secret_key') != get_secret_key():
            return err_authorization__invalid_secret_key, 401
```